# jQuery and url re-write

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I am having a wierd error and jQuery not working depending on how the url is written.

if the url is

```
/index.cfm?show=about-us
```

all is good. BUT if the url is

```
/index.cfm/show_about-us
```

jQuery doesn't seem to load correctly and I get a "$ is not defined" error in fireBug

I can't use the standard  ?= query string I need to be able to use the re-write method.

Any ideas are appriciated
Lance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your `<script src="...">` say?  I have a feeling it's looking for `/index.cfm/jquery.js` which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this was a reference issue to the files.  Evendently in that re-write sytle the dom is still trying to navigate the file system starting in the /show_about-us/ directory which isn't truely a directory.

Answer (score 0):

That's it. @recursive got it in one.

Consider using the absolute path from the root of your domain in src attributes. For example: `<script src="/jquery.js">`